# Prevent Django form inserting javascript that is loaded in head of page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I build an application with Django (version 2.2.1). All templates extend a base template, which loads jQuery as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

In one template, the combination of an autocompleting input field from django-autocomplete-light (version 3.4.1) and a datepicker from django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus (version 3.0.5) caused the date picker not to work, due to the bootstrap datepicker not being able to initialize jQuery.
It turns out that I stumbled upon the same problem as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644969/problem-when-creating-a-form-with-both-django-autocomplet-light-and-and-bootstra).

The problem is that the template contains a form, which contains a `ModelSelect2` widget. This widget causes the form to load jQuery again, as can be seen in its `media` property:

```
@property
def media(self):
    """Return JS/CSS resources for the widget."""
    extra = '' if settings.DEBUG else '.min'
    i18n_name = self._get_language_code()
    i18n_file = (
        '%s%s.js' % (I18N_PATH, i18n_name),
    ) if i18n_name else ()

    return forms.Media(
        js=(
            'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery%s.js' % extra,
            'autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js',
            'vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full%s.js' % extra,
        ) + i18n_file + (
            'autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js',
            'autocomplete_light/forward.js',
            'autocomplete_light/select2.js',
            'autocomplete_light/jquery.post-setup.js',
        ),
        css={...}, # omitted, because irrelevant for this question.
    )
```

My question: is it somehow possible to prevent this double loading a javascript file?

I guess that a form must be able to render itself without knowing what else has been rendered in front of it. So is it then somehow possible to inform a `Form` about any javascript that has already been included in the template so that a `Form.media()` can exclude javascript that is already loaded outside the form?

Oh sweet irony: while reviewing this question I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520816/in-django-problems-with-loading-jquery-with-multiple-plugins-or-how-to-load) and now I discovered that in a newer version of django-autocomplete-light jQuery has been removed from the media, solving my problem... Nevertheless, I am still interested in an answer to this question, because the problem might occur again with a different combination of widgets provided by external packages.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that's why sometimes you would have `{% block js %}` in the base of the template.

[how to organize JS files in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586259/how-to-organize-js-files-in-django)